# Developing a 2D Android game on Unity - Pros and Cons

Tags: 2d, android, unity

Depending on your experiences, if you have created a 2D game on Android using Unity, was it painful? Have you ever said "I wish I have used X instead of Unity!"?

Tell me the Pros, Cons and the name of "X" please.

Edit: Consider it for a commercial shoot em up game. The programming language can be anything.

Comment: The "pain" of creating a game on any platform can't be quantified. It's going to be different for every game and every developer. I'm voting to close as not constructive. This is essentially a "which technology to use" question. See the [FAQ] about what types of questions to ask here (and what kind not to ask).

Comment: Is it a purely commercial project or you would like to learn something from it as a programmer? What is your programming language? If you want to have practice and like C# then it's MonoGame.

Comment: @Den: Updated the question

Answer (score 4):

I have developed games using both the android sdk/andengine , as well as unity, and my personal preference is to go with the android sdk route. Unity is great, but seeing as this was my first trip into the mobile development world, I took this as a good excuse to learn the environment, and understand the constraints and pitfalls associated with it. Unity simplifies everything so much, making everything from debugging to deployment ten times easier, but I must say that from a personal perspective I don't feel like I got a darn thing out of it.

If your goal is rapid prototyping, or you simply aren't interested in the challenges or opportunities to learn associated with the android platform, then you should go with unity hands down. Otherwise, I would recommend the SDK.

Comment: I was looking for a rapid building but I'm not hesitated to face challenges. Then again, I see your point, thank you.

Comment: I've coded mobile apps for ~5 years (be it mostly iOS) and I have to say that Unity is NOT good for rapid prototyping. Having something run on a device takes ages because of the slow export to native code process. Sure you can test the game in editor, but you still have to test on device so often. The long export-build-launch times makes this process very very slow. Doing it with a native framework (like Cocos2d/Spritebuilder) is 10x faster.

Answer (score 3):

I have built 3D games that are played in two dimensions just fine in Unity3D. If you seek a true two dimensional game, I can tell you there are more suitable engines, Unity3D really focuses on the 3D realm.

The best answer I can give you based on the information you have provided. Hope it helps.